# Magento Custom Variable issue

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am in the process of writing a custom module whereby the user can enter a shipping cost per product.

I have added a custom variable to all of my products called 'initial_shipping_charge'. In my Get Shipping Rate function I am trying to loop through the products in my basket and get the variable (these will be added to a overall total).

The var_dump($shipping_price_initial); line returns NULL and not the variable that it contains - any idea why this is not working?

Thanks in advance.

```
protected function _getStandardShippingRate()
{
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    /* @var $rate Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method */

    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
    /**
     * getConfigData(config_key) returns the configuration value for the
     * carriers/[carrier_code]/[config_key]
     */


     $shipping_price_value = rand(10 , 50);

     //Create a basket session object
     $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {

        $item_id = $item->getId();
        $_basketProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item_id);

        $shipping_price_initial = $_basketProduct->getAttribute('initial_shipping_charge');

        var_dump($shipping_price_initial);
    }

    $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $rate->setMethod('standand');
    $rate->setMethodTitle('Standard');

    $rate->setPrice($shipping_price_value);
    $rate->setCost(0);

    return $rate;
}
```

Comment: If you do `Mage::log($_basketProduct->getData())` after loading the product (and obviously enabling your system log), can you see the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_basketProduct->getAttribute('initial_shipping_charge');
```

Should be

```
$_basketProduct->getData('initial_shipping_charge');
```

or

```
$_basketProduct->getInitialShippingCharge();
```

But i guess you don't even have the product cause you fetch the quote item id and try to load a product with that id....you need to:

```
$item->getProduct()
```

P.S.:

Product->Quote->Order

There is a conversion process, look for "quote to order conversion" or "product to quote item conversion"

Comment: @mishcha  : oops there is a typo error. I think you intended `$_basketProduct->getInitialShippingCharge();`

Comment: No joy I'm afraid - thanks for the suggestions though :)

Comment: Got this working after using $item->getProduct() - your help is much appreciated :)